# populating seed data from a join table javascript

Tags: javascript, join, knex.js, seeding

I have seed data for agents, listings and potential buyers for migration files using knex. I created a join table called listingsBuyers referencing the foreign key for listings and buyers. Is there a way to seed a join table referencing the the foreign key for listings and buyers? The way it is set up below is giving an error listing not defined.

I initially tried the lines I commented out. I received an error: insert or update on table "listingsBuyers" violates foreign key constraint "listingsbuyers_buyer_id_foreign"

```
exports.up = function(knex) {
    return knex.schema.createTable('listings', table =>{
        table.increments()
        table.string('address')
        table.integer('agent_id')
        table.foreign('agent_id').references('agents.id')
    })
};

exports.down = function(knex) {
    return knex.schema
        .dropTable('listings')
};
```

```
exports.up = function(knex) {
    return knex.schema.createTable('buyers', table =>{
        table.increments()
        table.string('name')
        table.integer('listing_id')
        table.foreign('listing_id').references('listings.id')
    })
};

exports.down = function(knex) {
    return knex.schema
        .dropTable('buyers')
};
```

this is the join table

```
exports.up = function(knex) {
    return knex.schema.createTable('listingsBuyers', table =>{
        table.increments()
        table.integer('listing_id')
        table.foreign('listing_id').references('listings.id')
        table.integer('buyer_id')
        table.foreign('buyer_id').references('buyers.id')
    })
};

exports.down = function(knex) {
    return knex.schema
        .dropTable('listingsBuyers')
};
```

the seed file

```
exports.seed = function(knex) {
  return knex('listingsBuyers').insert([
    {listing_id: listings.id , buyer_id: buyers.id},
    //{listing_id: 2, buyer_id: 1},
    //{listing_id: 3, buyer_id: 3}
  ])
  .then(() =>{//set the value for auto-incrementing
    return knex.raw(`SELECT setval('listingsBuyers_id_seq', (SELECT MAX(id) FROM listingsBuyers))`)
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the following:

```
exports.seed = function(knex) {
  return knex('listingsBuyers').insert([
    {listing_id: listings.id , buyer_id: buyers.id},
    //{listing_id: 2, buyer_id: 1},
    //{listing_id: 3, buyer_id: 3}
  ])
```

`listings.id` (in line 3) is not going to be defined and neither is `buyers.id`.

Not sure why you've commented out the next two lines because they might actually work. Try:

```
exports.seed = function(knex) {
  return knex('listingsBuyers').insert([
    { listing_id: 2, buyer_id: 1 },
    { listing_id: 3, buyer_id: 3 }
  ])
```

Comment: I initially tried the lines i commented out. I received an error: insert or update on table "listingsBuyers" violates foreign key constraint "listingsbuyers_buyer_id_foreign"

Comment: That would indicate that the matching buyer record didn't exist yet.